# Write Vault secret path if no VAULT_ADDR is present

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

Multiple secrets are resolved with Hashicorp Vault lookup plugin from the group_vars. The goal is to resolve the secrets if the playbook is run in the build pipeline. If the playbook is run in a local environment the secret path should be returned. The goal is to have the possibility to output all variables per host and perform a diff on group_var changes.

By initial thought was something like this:

```
top_secret: "{% set secret='secret/top_secret/key:value' %}{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret') if VAULT_ADDR else secret }}"
```

So if the environment variable "VAULT_ADDR" exists then it should resolve the secret "secret/top_secret/key:value" and if not use the string "secret/top_secret/key:value". Sadly this is not possible as group_var files do not get parsed by Jinja2.

What would work is:

```
top_secret: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/top_secret/key:value') if VAULT_ADDR is none else 'secret/top_secret/key:value' }}"
```

What I do not like is that the secret path is duplicated.

Are there any other options for this goal?

Answer (score 0):

> Sadly this is not possible as group_var files do not get parsed by Jinja2.

I'm not fully sure what do you mean by this, but you definitely can use Jinja2 in any group vars. I tried both your templates replacing `hashi_vault` lookup with `env` because I don't have a vault set up and they worked incorrectly until I fixed your condition expressions. But conceptually all of them are functioning:

```yaml
vault_addr: "{{ lookup('env', 'VAULT_ADDR') }}"
top_secret: "{% set secret='secret/top_secret/key:value' %}{{ lookup('env', 'SOMETHING') if vault_addr is defined and vault_addr else secret }}"
secret_path: secret/top_secret/key:value
non_top_secret: "{{ lookup('env', 'SOMETHING') if vault_addr is defined and vault_addr else secret_path }}"
```

When `VAULT_ADDR` is not set:

```
"top_secret": "secret/top_secret/key:value"
"non_top_secret": "secret/top_secret/key:value"
```

When `VAULT_ADDR` is set:

```
"top_secret": "something"
"non_top_secret": "something"
```

So generally it works. But, as you can see, readability is not that good. If you decide to fix it using multiline YAML, you will have to deal with odd whitespaces and newlines. It's possible but too hard and unnecessary.

A more clean way would be use of the [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ternary_filter.html) filter:

```yaml
---
vault_addr: "{{ lookup('env', 'VAULT_ADDR') }}"
secret_path: secret/top_secret/key:value
top_secret: "{{ vault_addr is defined and vault_addr | ternary(lookup('env', 'SOMETHING'), secret_path) }}"
```

Note that I also check `vault_addr` for length in an old school manner because I didn't use the `default` keyword of `env` lookup added in Ansible 2.13. If you're sure that it's not a problem for your case, this can be omitted.

While reviewing the docs, I just noticed that ternary filter also has `none_val` keyword parameter, so it may be even simpler to achieve. But I didn't play with it yet.

**EDIT:**
`hashi_vault` lookup documentation [suggests to migrate to other lookups/modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/hashi_vault/docsite/migration_hashi_vault_lookup.html#ansible-collections-community-hashi-vault-docsite-migration-hashi-vault-lookup) - partially because of these syntax complications.